# show and hide doesn't the opposite of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function show and hide,I want to show 300 line and when you press on more it should show the rest of the text but it doesn't the opposite of it, meaning it show all the text and when you click on more it show less.

Comment: I added jQuery to your snippet and other than having the conditions backwards it seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign "showcontent" class an initial style of "display:none;", then every thing should work as expected.

```
var html = firstcontent + '<p class="showcontent" style="display:none;">' + secondcontent + '</p><a href="" class="morebtn">' + show_more + '</a></p>';
```

Working demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/48r998f6/